# Django fill field value type expression based on multiple crieria

Tags: django, django-models

My project has two models boq and dpr model
Both the models contain building,level,activity and subactivity as foriegn keys 
I need to fill up the actual start on boq model with date in dprmodel when all the above mentioned fields are equaled

boq model

```
choicestype=(('start','start'),('finish','finish'))

class boqmodel(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    building = models.ForeignKey(building, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    level = models.ForeignKey(level, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    subactivity = models.ForeignKey(sub_activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    linkactivity = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True,blank=True)
    linktype = models.CharField(choices=choicestype,max_length=300,null=True,blank=True)
    linkduration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    plannedstart = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    plannedfinish = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    actualstart = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    actualfinish = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
DPR

class dprmodel(models.Model):
    Date=models.DateField()
    Contractor=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Building = models.ForeignKey(building, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Level = models.ForeignKey(level, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Activity = models.ForeignKey(activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Subactivity = models.ForeignKey(sub_activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Status=models.CharField(choices=choicestype,max_length=300)
    Labor=models.IntegerField()
Both the models have Building,Level,Activity,Sub Activity as common fields. My entry in BOQ

code=1
building=A-1
Level=L-1
Activity=Activity-1
Subactivity-Subactivity-1
duration=2
linkactivity=null
linktype=null
linkduration=null
planned start=01-01-2019(as linkactivity=null)
plannedfinish=03-01-2019(planned start+duration)
MY DPR Entry

Date :10-1-2019
contractor :A
building=A-1
Level=L-1
Activity=Activity-A
Subactivity=Subactivity-A
Status =Start
Labor=2
I need to populate the Actual start date in boqmodel such that if boqmodel.building = dprmodel.building and boqmodel.level = dprmodel.level and boqmodel.activity = dprmodel.activity and boqmodel.subactivity = dprmodel.subactivity and dpr.status=start.
```

If the above condition exists then boq.actualstart=dpr.date
*em

Comment: Seems like you need an additional model that stores the common fields that both models have a foreign key to

Comment: @ravieta, we don't care about your db schema, all lot of fields you write here had no sense for us. We don't want to waste time trying to understand all this fields. Learn [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With an MRE you will have a quick answer and other users can learn about your question and answers.